# How to use Offset and End.(xlDown) to Select data to graph

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Stacked Column Chart with the data in the table below.

I want to **Select** column A1:A9 and C1:F9.  The Selection also needs to be adaptive to different column sizes (i.e, someone adds another Feature).  The macro should also work for a table of data, anywhere in the Sheet. As long as the macro originates from the ActiveCell.

How do I not only Select until the column end, but also Select excluding the "Values" column.  I am trying to use End and Offset, but I am not sure the best way to do it.  And once again, I want to use it on a table that is anywhere in the sheet and then create a Stacked Column Chart from it.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code please. The idea is that you iteratively `Union` various ranges of the data based on the condition that the header is not 'Values'.

The working assumption is that the `CurrentRegion`  of the `ActiveCell` will select your table data. Where the definition of `CurrentRegion` is *'The current region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns. '* - [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx)

Then the code will append the first column to an output range. After that, the outer columns will only be appended to the output range if the header is not 'Values'.

```
Dim rngData As Range
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim rngToSelect As Range

Set rngData = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Set rngToSelect = Range(rngData.Cells(1, 1), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, 1))
For intCounter = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
    If rngData.Cells(1, intCounter).Value <> "Values" Then
        Set rngToSelect = Union(rngToSelect, Range(rngData.Cells(1, intCounter), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, intCounter)))
    End If
Next intCounter

rngToSelect.Select
```

[image]